Again on closing unclear questions with answers
Recently, I have seen this question closed with the motivation, "This question needs details or clarity," even though it already had two coherent answers before closing.
Looking for previous discussions about a similar issue here on Meta, I discovered that it is not a new problem ( see, for instance, this discussion). I note that in the present case, the editing did not change the meaning of the question. Honestly, I think that, in this case, the need for more details or clarity is the reason for closing the question more than the question itself.
However, I am presenting the specific case just as an example of a general tendency on which I would like to draw more attention.
Sometimes, I get the impression that some community members tend to interpret their role as severe censors when voting for closing questions more than acting to benefit this site's reputation. Reputation that is already not very nice.
The two related questions I would like to ask here are the following:

Is it possible that careless votes could result as a side effect of the gamification of voting mechanisms (badges)?
Could fewer available votes per day foster more considered votes?


Which badges do you have in mind for your first point? There are no gamification rewards for closing questions.

@ACuriousMind: Moderation badges: Vox populi, Suffrage, Electorate, Steward, Reviewer? Civic duty.

@Qmechanic I explicitly wrote that "I am presenting the specific case just as an example". I am not interested in discussing the example. I am interested in the issue of questions closed as unclear, even if they already received a couple of relevant answers. Therefore, I find the tag specific-question misleading and I am going to delete it.

I agree with your concern and I think all we can do is to encourage users to prefer hitting "skip" over making a rash/careless decisions when voting. Most (though not all) of us have asked some question, and it's easy to understand how it's never a nice feeling when it gets closed without that closure being warranted. If someone prefers a badge over giving due consideration, that's just sad imo, but as the site is currently designed I see no way to change such a behavior other than appealing to sanity and reason :)

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Vox Populi, Suffrage, Civic Duty and Electorate are for up/down votes of questions, not for close votes. Steward and Reviewer are for completing review tasks, but you can complete a close review task by either voting to close or clicking "Leave Open", i.e. those incentivize reviewing, not closing.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 : Noted.

FWIW, answers are fully irrelevant as to whether a question is on topic or not. If 3 people think it's unclear, they're fully allowed to close it. If 3 other people think it's clear, they're fully allowed to re-open it. I sincerely doubt there's any gamification here, just people operating how they best judge questions (which obviously differs from how you do/do not judge questions) which is entirely the point of the SE model.

@KyleKanos Here, the point is not whether a question is on topic or not but whether it is clear. It is a different issue. If there are answers and they are coherent with the question, it could be a signal that those who voted for closing may not have carefully considered or understood the question. Nobody is claiming that they can't vote for closing. But, when it happens that such closing votes with the motivation of a non-clear question are quite frequent in the case of a few persons, some doubt that they interpret in a too severe way their role is possible.

...the point is not whether a question is on topic or not but whether it is clear since "unclear what you're asking" is a valid closure reason, I fail to see how this is not discussing topicality. If there are answers...it could be a signal that those who voted for closing may not have carefully considered or understood the question It could also be that they chose to vote the question based on the question as they're supposed to, rather than on the question and answers as you're incorrectly asserting should be done.

Feel free to disagree with any closures, that is how this site is supposed to operate. But asserting that there's either purposeful animosity by a select few or, worse, idiocy, and raising a stink about it on Meta is just a waste of time. You just need to leave a comment along the lines of "I don't know why this question was closed, OP seems to mean...." and vote to reopen, then move on.

I think that the purpose in to close questions is a (maybe a little aggressive) invitation for the asker to think more about what they want to ask and how, before to receive answers about something that maybe would not be what they want to be answered.
I agree that to have your question closed is a little bit scary in the first moment; my first question here was closed for being a duplicate and I went to sleep with the light on that night. But it is the part of the experience to understand that it is not so bad, you can rewrite and submit it to be reopened, and usually people are nice (I think) about reopening questions.
About your first point (gamification), it would be true for other edition tools, even reopening votes, so it's hard to tell how much it really influence the system working. Some edits would be more carefully made, others would be careless, and there is nothing we could do as a community about that.
I don't believe that fewer available votes would automatically imply in more careful votes. It seems a fallacy of the converse.

Despite to not agree with your points, I agree that the clear/unclear criterion is the most subjective one to close a question. Maybe the site could start to ask why is that unclear in a brief summary, or to have a list of possible reasons about why the question is unclear.

I do not think that presenting what I consider a problem should be regarded as aggressive. I was trying to speak frankly about that, and I stressed I was using a case just as an example without any desire to discuss that specific issue. I know that communication through posts and comments is quite delicate and that there is a risk of misunderstanding. Still, I thought people here should have enough experience to avoid personalization. Maybe I was wrong, and I apologize if anybody found my tone inappropriate.

I happen to think it’s a terrible question.
First, a question of the form “why do some physicists believe this or that” is not answerable.  Certainly some physicists believe this but not all physicists do.  If you want to know why person A believes something, ask person A: don’t ask person B why person A believes it.
Next, the falsification argument is not always relevant.  Some branches of physics have now gone waaaay beyond what is falsifiable: string theory is the usual culprit, so are many areas of cosmology.  The reality is that many fields of physics cannot wait for experiments to catch up, and this isn’t a reason to ignore fields (some will differ on this conclusion).  It may take time to develop falsifiable consequences of a theory, and even longer for the hardware to catch up (think gravitational waves or the demonstration of speed up of some quantum information algorithms).
On balance, the question basically asks for people to venture guesses as to the motivation of others, and the supporting argument is based on the idea that theories can be tested in a (relatively) short time, which is not always the case.

I happen to think you are not replying to my post. The issue I hoped to discuss was clearly stated: starting on my subjective feeling that *Sometimes, I get the impression that some community members tend to interpret their role as severe censors when voting for closing questions more than acting to benefit this site's reputation.*I asked two related questions. Maybe the first one could be considered a guess. Still, it is intended to advance a rational guess for an existing behavior: some closing reasons do not have an understandable connection with the closed question.  ...

The second is a proposal to enhance a more careful voting process. Of course, if you feel that we have the perfect voting system and understandable reasons for closing questions are irrelevant, I understand you disagree with my point of view.  But please, do not transform it into something completely different.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Check your premises. No one need answer questions that are fundamentally built on a mistake or two.

sorry it seems I was not clear and I apologize for that: the question is bad.  People voted to close the question, not the answers, and they have valid reasons to close the question.   The answers do not matter when the question is not clear and I don't see any evidence of gamification when VoC a bad question.  The site wants to provide definitive answers, not opinions.

Let me add the following: I completely fail to understand your comments about badges.  Frankly, does anybody care about an extra badge?

@ZeroTheHero Probably nobody cares about badges. However, it was the nicest reason I could imagine for some evident sloppy decisions about closing questions. Any alternative hypothesis would presumably be worse. Anyway, with the answers to this post, I got confirmation that some people frequenting Meta think everything is fine and there is no problem with the closing votes. I'll consider it the message to take home.
